# Laravel Paypal - pass shipping address from website

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I just implemented the PayPal API for Laravel from net-shell (https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal) and everything works fine so far, but now there's one thing I'm missing or I don't know how to do: In my portal, users have to register with their address. What I want is that this email (that was used for registering at my portal) is used as shipping address and is later also shown when on the PayPal site (so there is no matter what address the user entered for PayPal).

Is there any way to do this?

I know that there seems to be a PayPal:ShippingAdress, which I can use, but if this is the right one, how can I assign it to the payment then?

**Edit**: I now tried lots of variations with something like `$transaction->setShippingAddress();` or `$payer->setShippingAddress();` or `$payment->setShippingAddress();` but nothing works, the method is never found. Now in Paypal/Api/ShippingAddress I found the method setDefaultAddress, so I thought about creating such an object and use this method like so:

```
$shippingAddress = [
            "recipient_name" => "John Johnson",
            "line1" => "Whatever street 2",
            "line2" => "Another street 2",
            "city" => "London",
            "country_code" => "UK",
            "postal_code" => "NR30 1LY",
            "state" => "England",
            "phone" => "3123123123"
        ];

        $shippingAddr = PayPal::ShippingAddresss();
        $shippingAddr->setDefaultAddress($shippingAddress);
```

Don't get an error using this code but also it's not setting the address, I need to assign this created shippingAddress object to the payment or transaction now, like I do it with details, creating details object and then using `$amount->setDetails($details);`, but I'm not finding anything for the shippingAddress.....

**Edit2**:
Getting to the hint with the item list, this is how I create and set that list:

```
 $itemList = PayPal::itemList();

        foreach ($items as $item)
                $product = Product::where('id', '=', $item->product->id)->first();
                $itemName = $product->name;
                $itemPrice = $product->price;
                $itemAmount = $item->amount;
                $payPalItem = PayPal::item();
                $payPalItem->setName($itemName)
                    ->setDescription($itemName)
                    ->setCurrency('EUR')
                    ->setQuantity($itemAmount)
                    ->setPrice($itemPrice);
                $itemList->addItem($payPalItem);
            }
```

and then

```
$transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setItemList($itemList);
```

Comment: no ideas anybody?

Comment: Just a quick bit of information for you, when you are selling things through Paypal if you do not ship the item to the address on their account you have no seller protection. Just an FYI

Comment: Same problem as me. I'm not recommended dude. I used it before with 5.2. It worked. But, I can't pass address. I tried to follow Paypal doc, but nothing can pre-loaded in paypal checkout page. Customer need to key-in again their address detail and phone number as a guest checkout. I'm not test yet this api https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment. But, it look like more documentation.

Comment: It worked means just basic flow working. You may confuse my comment.

Comment: @KelvinKyaw check out the accepted answer, i had a long research with him but got it working now!

Comment: @nameless Thanks. I will take a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chat-research done with the author of question (@nameless - greetings!), we found that the place to add another shipping address is the itemList:

You gather items to your order

```
 $itemList = PayPal::itemList();

    foreach ($items as $item)
            $product = Product::where('id', '=', $item->product->id)->first();
            $itemName = $product->name;
            $itemPrice = $product->price;
            $itemAmount = $item->amount;
            $payPalItem = PayPal::item();
            $payPalItem->setName($itemName)
                ->setDescription($itemName)
                ->setCurrency('EUR')
                ->setQuantity($itemAmount)
                ->setPrice($itemPrice);
            $itemList->addItem($payPalItem);
        }
```

And the final move is to attach address to $itemList

```
$shippingAddress = [
                "recipient_name" => "John Johnson",
                "line1" => "Whatever street 2",
                "line2" => "Another street 2",
                "city" => "London",
                "country_code" => "GB",
                "postal_code" => "NR30 1LY",
                "state" => "England",
                "phone" => "3123123123"
            ];

$itemList->setShippingAddress($shippingAddres);
```

Be aware that country is in ISO 3166-1, so GB - not UK. If you enter wrong two letter code - the response will return 400 code malformed.

Comment: thx for the answer - but it seems like setShippingAddress ist not available on the transaction.. I'm getting `Call to undefined method PayPal\Api\Transaction::setShippingAddress()`

Comment: also, in PayPal/api/Shipping address i found ` /**
     * Default shipping address of the Payer.
     *
     * @param bool $default_address
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDefaultAddress($default_address)
    {
        $this->default_address = $default_address;
        return $this;
    }`

Comment: so maybe add $payer->setShippingAddress ??

Comment: same result... method not found... what I'm thinking about is if i need something like `$shippingAddr = new ShippingAddress` and then use `$shippingAddr->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)` but where do I assign this then...

Comment: $shipping = PayPal::setShippingAddress(); $shipping->setLine1('my first line); ??

Comment: `Call to undefined method Netshell\Paypal\Paypal::setShippingAddress()`

Comment: One more thing, When they make request, it seems, that shipping address is bound with itemList  , see the sample request somewhere here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments and show us, where do you add Items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135123/discussion-between-cssblaster21895-and-nameless).

Comment: here comes your bounty :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a IPN in paypal to check if the session attributes is passed correctly. In case the user uses different email the transaction is invalidated.

Comment: How does this relate to my answer? I basically need to pass an shipping adress to the paypal API so it doesn't use the one in the paypal system but the one that the customer used when registering on my page.